# Active Directory - Search by multiple attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, active-directory, visual-studio-2013

I am making a web program designed in Visual Studio 2013, ASP, C#.

I am looking for a way to be able to search the Active Directory to obtain email addresses to send automated emails when a report is generated.  My requirement is to obtain the email address to individuals based on their job title and their location (i.e. New York, Dallas, etc.).

I was thinking along the lines of creating two lists (one for the TO: addresses and the other for the CC: addresses).  I was going to use lists because the amount of people that will be getting the emails vary based on the site location and type of report.

My problem is I do not know how to set up the search parameters in order to populate these lists.  Research I have done indicates that I will need to use System.DirectoryServices to create a DirectorySearcher.

All this is going to be done under the "Submit Report" button click event.

Comment: @Lankymart I don't appreciate the language or the insults you used in the edit reason. Please do not disrespect other users.

Comment: @Lankymart - That edit reason was completely inappropriate, as Chris said. No matter how you feel about an asker, please remain polite in your comments and edit suggestions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you need:

> ```
>      string filter = @"(&(objectCategory=Person)(physicalDeliveryOfficeName=Dallas))";
> ```

Then search for the mail addresses:

```
     List<string> list = GetMail(filter);
```

.

```
  List<string> GetMail(string SearchFilter)
  {
     List<string> MailAddresses = new List<string>();
      using (DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher())
      {
      directorySearcher.Filter = SearchFilter;
      SearchResultCollection resultCollection = directorySearcher.FindAll();

     foreach (SearchResult searchResult in resultCollection)
      {
         try
         {
            MailAddresses.Add(searchResult.Properties["mail"][0].ToString());
         }
         catch {
                //Maybe fill a list of errors here.
               }
      } 
  }
     return MailAddresses;
  }
```